# Kinect V2 on Jackal by Clearpath

Tags: ros, kinect, urdf, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm new to ROS and have gone through the basic tutorials. I'm trying to get the kinect V2 connected with the Jackal and setting up simulations with Gazebo, rviz and stage.  The jackal packages that I downloaded has the SICK laser range already set up but I want to replace it with the Kinect V2. From what I have gathered from reading online is that I need to modify the jackal_description urdf. Can anyone help me and tell me what exactly I need to do to get to edit the urdf and simulated kinect data, so that I can progress towards mapping a room?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225346/kinect--v2-on-jackal-by-clearpath/) by [richardsondynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/25769/richardsondynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [tutorial](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/guides/ros/ROS%20Navigation%20Basics.html#customization) on customizing the Jackal's URDF.  You could use a kinect from the description example from the [husky](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/indigo-devel/husky_description/urdf/accessories/kinect_camera.urdf.xacro).  This will be a Kinect V1 but gazebo treats both as a RGBD sensor.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2016-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luispineda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25717/luispineda/) on 2016-01-30**:
@tonybaltovski Thank you for your reply, When I tried to run rviz (roslauch jackal_viz view_robot.launch) I the an error "roslaunch: command not found" do you know why is this happening?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-01-30**:
Did you setup your environment?  `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` or if it is a workspace: `source PATH_TO_WS/devel/setup.bash`

**Comment by [M@tt](https://answers.ros.org/users/26035/m@tt/) on 2016-02-22**:
Is there anything else you have to do besides modify the URDF? I'm also trying to connect a Kinect to a Jackal. I assume you also need to install the clearpathrobotics/iai_kinect2 package. And I assume that you need to modify the launch files as well?

**Comment by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on 2018-07-21**:
I'm also trying to integrate the kinect xacros from the husky into the jackal, but I can't get the sensor to show up in rviz, or publish, even though everything 'looks right' and the description is compiled without errors. What should I do in this case?

**Comment by [spiritninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/39726/spiritninja/) on 2019-06-20**:
the command is `roslaunch` unlike the mistake on the clearpath webpage `roslauch`.